# filter out <!-- -->

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to filter out `<!--T:0.4221 sec S:192.168.173.3-->` from the below string

It should filter out all the occurrences of `<!-- -->` in my text

```
{"success":{"id":"10364907","email_address":"a@a.com"}}<!--T:0.4221 sec S:192.168.173.3-->
```

This is not working for me

```
$.trim(html.replace(/<!--(.*?)-->/ig, ''));
```

The end result should look like

```
{"success":{"id":"10364907","email_address":"a@a.com"}}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4F2Zn/. Could it be that you are not assigning the return value of `$.trim` back to the variable?

Comment: Yep, should work. As @Felix pointed out to me, my answer was really the same (that's why I deleted it... thanks Felix for pointing that out).

Answer (score 3):

It works, check that you have included any **jquery version** as you are using [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)

```
var html='{"success":{"id":"10364907","email_address":"a@a.com"}}<!--T:0.4221 sec S:192.168.173.3-->';
console.log(html);
html=$.trim(html.replace(/<!--(.*?)-->/ig, ''));
console.log(html);
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B2MNA/)

If you don't want to add **Jquery** then use [javascript trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) like,

```
html=(html.replace(/<!--(.*?)-->/ig, '')).trim();
```